# owlready2 rdfs:subClassOf inference doesn't work

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs, rdflib, owlready

I created an rdflib graph and serialised it into an owl file formatted as XML. I explicitly write `A RDF.type RDFS.Class` and `B RDFS.subClassOf A`. After I do this.

```
    onto = owlready2.get_ontology("file://D:/Uni/cs/courses/bdrp/bdrp_sch_kb/code/test1.owl").load()
    owlready2.sync_reasoner()
    onto.save("test2.owl", format='rdfxml')
```

But when I open the `test2.owl`, there is no `B RDF.type RDFS.Class`. So, `B`'s type was not inferred. Does `owlready2` reasoner even work?

Comment: the reasoner works. The inference itself is not something an OWL reasoner does cover. You're mixing RDFS inference with OWL inference, OWL != RDFS . I also don'T see the benefit of what you did. In OWL classes are of type `owl:Class` and it also holds that every `owl:Class` is subclass of `rdfs:Class``- what you did is basically useless - so what is the use case of your inference? Just create OWL classes and you're done

Comment: Yes, but OWL inference includes RDFS:inferences, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, I replace rdfs:Class with Owl:Class and it still doesn't infer

Comment: infer what? This is a trivial axiom, see https://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl# - there is no need for inference

Comment: It doesn’t see the subclassof Owl:Class as Owl:class. When I assert B is an Owl:Class and A is subclassof B and run graph.subjects(rdf.type, Owl:Class) it doesn’t return A but only B